# Opencart: USPS not showing International Services on checkout

Tags: opencart2.x, usps

opencart2.0.1.1

USPS setting:-Weight Class= Pound, Geo Zone= All Zones,  Dimensions (L x W x H)=10x10x10,  Zip Code=33446

product:- Weight Class = Pound, Dimensions (L x W x H)=10x10x10, Weight =4.

it is working properly in Domestic Services But  International Services is not showing when i m checkout using other country(Mexico),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find out `$this->config->get('usps_girth')` not returning any value,

So i use formula to find out  girth = L + W * 2 + H * 2 ;

In \catalog\model\shipping\usps.php i have changed at line 300 aprx.

From usps.php

```
$xml .= '       <Container>' . $this->config->get('usps_container') . '</Container>';
$xml .= '       <Size>' . $this->config->get('usps_size') . '</Size>';
$xml .= '       <Width>' . $this->config->get('usps_width') . '</Width>';
$xml .= '       <Length>' . $this->config->get('usps_length') . '</Length>';
$xml .= '       <Height>' . $this->config->get('usps_height') . '</Height>';
$xml .= '       <Girth>' . $this->config->get('usps_girth') . '</Girth>';
$xml .= '       <CommercialFlag>N</CommercialFlag>';
$xml .= '   </Package>';
$xml .= '</IntlRateV2Request>';
$request = 'API=IntlRateV2&XML=' . urlencode($xml);
```

To usps.php

```
//$this->config->get('usps_girth') -> to -> girth = L + W * 2 + H * 2          
$girth =($this->config->get('usps_width'))+(($this->config->get('usps_length'))*2)+(($this->config->get('usps_height'))*2);

$xml .= '       <Container>' . $this->config->get('usps_container') . '</Container>';
$xml .= '       <Size>' . $this->config->get('usps_size') . '</Size>';
$xml .= '       <Width>' . $this->config->get('usps_width') . '</Width>';
$xml .= '       <Length>' . $this->config->get('usps_length') . '</Length>';
$xml .= '       <Height>' . $this->config->get('usps_height') . '</Height>';
$xml .= '       <Girth>' . $girth . '</Girth>';
$xml .= '       <CommercialFlag>N</CommercialFlag>';
$xml .= '   </Package>';
$xml .= '</IntlRateV2Request>';
$request = 'API=IntlRateV2&XML=' . urlencode($xml);
```